# Android: How do I create a function that will be executed only once?

Tags: android

How can i create a function that will be run only once, on first installation? I am trying to create an information that displays one time.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Language? Target platform? Framework? ... any information at all?

Comment: i mentioned in the title as Android. So basically that's java and xml. thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use a flag in the [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Then on every startup you check this flag. If it is not set you display your first time message and then set the flag.

For example:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean firstStart = settings.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

       if(firstStart) {
          //display your Message here

          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
          editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
          editor.commit();
       }
    }
```